# Where should I put this using statement?

Tags: c#

I'm working with `System.DirectoryServices` and I have the following method that I use to create the `DirectoryEntry`:

```
static DirectoryEntry CreateDirectoryEntry(string connectionPath)
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = null;

    try
    {
        ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(AD_DOMAIN_NAME))
        ldapConnection.Path = connectionPath;
        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Caught in createDirectoryEntry():\n\n" + ex.ToString());
    }

    return ldapConnection;
}
```

This method is called in this manner:

```
DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = CreateDirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Example,DC=domain,DC=com");
```

I read that it is best practice to use a `using` statement for anything that implements `IDisposable`. My question is, do I need a `using` statement just in the `CreateDirectoryEntry()` method or should I also do it for each call?

To illustrate what I mean, is this sufficient?:

```
static DirectoryEntry CreateDirectoryEntry(string connectionPath)
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = null;

    try
    {
        using (ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(AD_DOMAIN_NAME))
        {
            ldapConnection.Path = connectionPath;
            ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Caught in createDirectoryEntry():\n\n" + ex.ToString());
    }

    return ldapConnection;
}
```

Or would I also need to use a `using` statement on the call like this?:

```
using (DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = CreateDirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Example,DC=domain,DC=com"))
{
    //Do something with ldapConnection
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Note:** I can't use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` for this solution so please keep answers related to `System.DirectoryServices`. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to return it then of course you will have to keep it outside using

Comment: Here's the [pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) for dealing with a disposable item that you return from a method.  The idea is to only dispose of it if and exception occurs and cannot be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last code-snippet is the way to go, otherwise you'd be returning a disposed ldapConnection to your caller - not a good thing.

And +1 for using using!!

Comment: When you put it like that, it makes so much more sense. I was definitely over-thinking this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet will dispose `ldapConnection` before returning it, therefore returning a disposed object which you obviously don't need.

Your function should look something like this:

```
static DirectoryEntry CreateDirectoryEntry(string connectionPath)
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = null;

    try
    {
        ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(AD_DOMAIN_NAME)
        ldapConnection.Path = connectionPath;
        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Caught in createDirectoryEntry():\n\n" + ex.ToString());
    }

    return ldapConnection;
}
```

While the second snippet is **correct**: to properly dispose of the `DirectoryEntry`, you should be using `using`.

Comment: This should include `finally` to properly dispose of the object if something goes wrong.

Comment: @neverendingqs That would be true if the exception wasn't swallowed.

Comment: @juharr - `finally` will always be called even if it goes into the `catch`.

Comment: @neverendingqs No, I mean the finally isn't needed because the exception is caught and nothing is thrown, so the `DirectoryEntry` will be returned and presumably should not be disposed.  Now, should they be swallowing all exceptions here?  Probably not.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for including the bit about not catching all exceptions like this. This lead me to research why that is bad and I learned something new. I will definitely refactor my code and only catch specific exceptions that need to be caught. +1

Comment: @Sylverac You might find using Code Analysis useful.  It will point out a number of things like that in your code.